# Creating a calculated measure to display prev month value

Tags: ssas, mdx, multidimensional-cube

I have a cube(multidimensional) in SSAS which contains a dimension with a period hierarchy(year, month, periodcategory, periodcode) and a measure "Amount"

Now i try to make a calculated measure which returns the value Amount for the previous month - value Amount for the current month (this will then only be different from the current amount when drilled down to month in the period hierarchy).
I read a lot of posts already about ParallelPeriod function or lag(1) but i don't see how this could help me in this case.

Any advice would be really helpful.

Comment: Why don't any of the posts you read help?   What is different about your cube that prevents the solutions that work for others from working for you?

Comment: I too thought ParallelPeriod would be perfect here. Maybe you could post a simple MDX query first: one that shows how you get values for the current month (or a hardcoded month). Then we can advise how to gradually develop that query.